# Shopify Graphql - Getting all products metafields

Tags: next.js, graphql, shopify

I am trying to implement a custom storefront using nextJS and shopify APIs.
One of the features I need to implement is a custom catalog filtering system which I want to handle using metafields.

So basically I do want to fetch ALL products metafields using the GraphQL Shopify Admin API in the most efficient way.

I do understand that shopify is telling me that this query is too extensive for it to be handled but I thought it was a fairly simple query. I'm trying to find alternative solutions that wouldn't involve querying all products one by one.

Any ideas?

Heres what I did:

To start tackling this task, i'm struggling to understand why can't I fetch all my products metafields using this ADMIN api query:

```
query GetProductsMetafields {
  products(first: 20) {
    nodes {
      id
      metafields(first: 15) {
        nodes {
          id
          key
          value
          namespace
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response given is the following:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Query cost is 2702, which exceeds the single query max cost limit (1000).\n\nSee https://shopify.dev/concepts/about-apis/rate-limits for more information on how the\ncost of a query is calculated.\n\nTo query larger amounts of data with fewer limits, bulk operations should be used instead.\nSee https://shopify.dev/api/usage/bulk-operations/queries for usage details.\n",
      "extensions": {
        "code": "MAX_COST_EXCEEDED",
        "cost": 2702,
        "maxCost": 1000,
        "documentation": "https://shopify.dev/api/usage/rate-limits"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

theres a bit more info in the [documentation](https://shopify.dev/docs/custom-storefronts/building-with-the-storefront-api/products-collections/metafields)
but it doesn't show how to fetch all products metafields.

Comment: Have you tried querying 10 or 20 products at a time instead of 50?

Comment: @MichelFloyd I guess I could, i'll try to do a bulk operation an report back.

Comment: I did do it as a bulk operation which was very tricky and intricate but ended up making it work. However it takes a very long time to complete. I find it weird as i'm only trying to query 20 products and 15 metafields at a time

Comment: But how many nodes are there in between? How many total branches in that tree? I'm not familiar with how shopify computes query cost but they clearly don't like yours. Have you tried their support department to see if there's another path to querying metafields?

Answer (score 1):

An efficient way would be to store product / metafields (or whatever data) on a database managed by your app, and then build your filtering system on top of it.

Your database can be maintained up to date by subscribing to products webhooks, and by periodically using bulkOperations to get fresh data

Also, **[Collection](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2024-01/resources/collection)** and **[SmartCollection](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2024-01/resources/smartcollection)** resources may also be interesting